# How Do I DataBind A Pie Chart Within A DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, datalist

I have the following resultant data coming from SQL Server tables

```
Product_ID  Unit_Type  Product_Pic    TotalUnique   TotalFail  Yield
1           Lawn Mower Lawnmower.jpg  470           27         94.25
2           Bicycle    Bicycle.jpg    5             1          80
3           Tractor    Tractor.jpg    0             0          100
5           Blender    Blender.jpg    360           12         96.66
6           Fridge     Fridge.jpg     11            6          94.59
```

I have a datalist that shows  each product with the given information.  I want to add a simple pie chart for each product in the datalist that uses Total Unique and TotalFail.  I've looked everywhere and cannot find a way to have each product pie chart use the data that is bound to the datalist.  It seems that I have to bind data to the datalist and as well bind data specifically to the chart.

I guess my question is can I do this?  If so can you steer me in the right direction?

Here is some more background information.  My Datalist looks like this (with the chart commented out.

```
   <asp:DataList ID="ProductDataList" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" CellPadding="10" HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" 
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="90%" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ProductDataList_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <ItemTemplate>

           <asp:Label ID="lblProductName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Unit_Type") %>' /><br /><br />
           <asp:Label ID="lblUniqueTests" runat="server" Text='<%# "Unique Tests: " + Eval("TotalUnique") %>' /><br />
           <asp:Label ID="lblFailedTests" runat="server" Text='<%# "Failed Tests: " + Eval("TotalFail") %>' /><br />
           <asp:Label ID="lblYield" runat="server" Text='<%# "Yield: " + Eval("Yield", "{0:0.00}") + "%" %>' /><br /><br />
           <asp:Image ID="imgProductImage" runat="server" ImageURL='<%# "Images/" + Eval("Product_Pic") %>'/><br /><br /><br />

            <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
                <Series>
                    <asp:Series Name="PieData" ChartType="Pie"></asp:Series>
                </Series>
                <ChartAreas>
                    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
                </ChartAreas>
            </asp:Chart>

        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

Here is part of the code that I use to populate the Datalist.

```
    lsSQL = "SELECT Product_ID, Product_Type, Unit_Type, Product_Pic, t.TotalUnique, t.TotalFail, ";
    lsSQL = lsSQL + "IsNull(((TotalUnique - NullIf(TotalFail, 0)) / Convert(Numeric(38, 2), TotalUnique) * 100), 100) AS Yield ";
    lsSQL = lsSQL + "FROM ";
    lsSQL = lsSQL + "( ";
    lsSQL = lsSQL + "SELECT Products.Product_ID, Products.Product_Type, Products.Unit_Type, Products.Image, ";
    lsSQL = lsSQL + "(Select COUNT(DISTINCT Functional_Tests.UUT_Serial_Number) AS MyCount FROM Functional_Tests ";
    lsSQL = lsSQL + "    WHERE Time_Stamp >= '" + txtDateFrom.Text + "' AND Time_Stamp <= '" + txtDateTo.Text + "' AND Product_ID = Products.Product_ID) AS TotalUnique, ";
    lsSQL = lsSQL + "(Select COUNT(DISTINCT Functional_Tests.UUT_Serial_Number) AS MyCount FROM Functional_Tests ";
    lsSQL = lsSQL + "    WHERE Time_Stamp >= '" + txtDateFrom.Text + "' AND Time_Stamp <= '" + txtDateTo.Text + "' AND Product_ID = Products.Product_ID AND Test_Result = 'Fail' ) AS TotalFail ";
    lsSQL = lsSQL + "FROM Products WHERE " + DBProduct_ID_String;
    lsSQL = lsSQL + " ) t";

    SqlConnection DBConnection = new SqlConnection(cnnString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = lsSQL;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = DBConnection;
    cmd.Connection.Open();

    ProductDataList.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    ProductDataList.DataBind();
```

Comment: **Don't use string concatenation to generate SQL.** Use parameters!

Comment: One Pie  can only have one Series.

Comment: @TaW ... changed.  Thanks!  Any idea how to bind the data to the pie chart??

Comment: @Dai ... The string DBProduct_ID_String has variable text within it depending on what he user chooses.  It has something like this "Product_ID = 1 OR Product_ID = 2 OR Product_ID = 3" or "Product_ID = 7 OR Product_ID = 8".  How would I use parameters?  As well do you have any idea how I would bind the data to the pie chart within the datalist??

Comment: The normal way should do: bind to the series.Points !

Comment: @TaW... could you be as so kind as to give me a small example with the code that I have provided above?  I don't know how to do what you are saying.  It seems I can only bind the data to the datalist.  How do I reference the data for the pie chart?

Comment: @andy: I always try to give only tested code, but as I don't do ASP this is a bit hard. The basics sholud workd the very same for APS and winforms chats. You ususally bind the Points collection of a Series to a datasource. If the source has multiple bindble fields you either  first set the XValueMember and YValueMembers the set the DataSource and finally call DataBind. Or you could use .Points.DataBindXY with two bindable data collection as paramters. The former is probably simpler here.

Comment: Minimal winforms example `Series s = chart6.Series.Add("pie");
s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
s.XValueMember = "x";
s.YValueMembers = "z";
chart6.DataSource = dt;
chart6.DataBind();` where`dt` is a `DataTable` containing columns `x` with a name and `z` with a number.. Not sure how to use a Reder here or if you can do it without reading multiple times.. With a DataTable and a DtatView you could use a Filter for restricting to one product..

Comment: @Andy Use a table-valued parameter with a `JOIN` for `WHERE x IN ( 1, 2, ... )`-type predicates (specifically: `FROM Products INNER JOIN @tvp AS t ON Products.Product_Id = t.ProductId`)

Comment: @TaW and Dai, thank you very much for your helpful responses.  Unfortunately my original question is still open.  I have no problem binding data to a standalone pie chart.  However, I'm not sure how to populate the pie chart when it is contained within a datalist.

Comment: I can only guess. Maybe filling the data into a DataSet and then binding both the DataList and the chart(s) to the DataSet is the way? Good luck and do post he solution if you find one!!